# C++ experimental/filesystem remove_all

Tags: c++

I want to remove folder with subfolders and files in C++17. I'm using `experimental/filesystem`

```
namespace filesys = std::experimental::filesystem;
...

uintmax_t n = filesys::remove_all("tmp");
cout << "Deleted " << n << " files or directories\n";
```

but when i run this code, program throw exception

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::filesystem_error'
>
> what():  filesystem error: cannot remove all: Directory not empty [tmp]
>
> Aborted

Using compier g++ 5.4.0

Documentation says:

> Deletes the contents of p (if it is a directory) and the contents of all its subdirectories, recursively, then deletes p itself as if by repeatedly applying the POSIX remove. Symlinks are not followed (symlink is removed, not its target)

Is there any problem with my code?

Comment: where is tmp located? Where you run the executable? Otherwise you need to specify the full path

Comment: `experimental` is not from the C++ standard, but from some separate Technical Specification. In C++17 you just use `std::filesystem::remove_all`.

Comment: deW1: tmp is in same folder as program ... i crated folder with tmp files and then i want clean

Comment: Let me guess: windows OS?

Comment: @kerreksb : i don't have <filesystem> header in system

Comment: no, it's Mint 18.1

Comment: Do you have the right privileges?

Comment: @karolyHorvath: yes, privileges set to 777

Comment: The code you provided works fine with Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10.

Comment: you know you can also pass the error code as second parameter and see if gets you anything back

Comment: @gomess: Then you don't have a C++17 compiler :-) (Wait, C++17 hasn't been published yet...)

Comment: @kerreksb: release date was march 2017

Comment: Are all the subdirectories set to `777` permission too? Does the directory have the sticky bit set? If it does, only the owner of files can remove them.

Comment: @barmar: ye, everything has all permissions

Comment: problem occurs only when i try remove folder with subfolder. Folder with files is OK

Answer (score 5):

The case of this error being thrown, is likely an issue in the implementation for gcc 5.4:
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71313

Using a more recent version of gcc will not throw such an error. For instance, this is not thrown for an empty `remove_all` call on gcc 7.4.0.

Comment: I can confirm here that it is a gcc version issue. Happens for me also on 5.4.0. The same call on 7.4.0 compiled code does not face this issue. So using an upgraded gcc version should help.