# experimental::filesystem::remove_all() : Permission denied

Tags: c++, filesystems, c++17, removeall

Say I have a few files inside folders inside a folder, e.g.:

```
folder1
    |- folder11
    |      |- file1
    |
    |- folder12
           |- file2
```

All these files and folders are created during runtime of my program and shall be deleted afterwards. For that, I was trying to use `std::experimental::filesystem::remove_all(path)` with `path` being either a relative or absolute path to `folder1` (I tried both). This should delete the files and folders recursively, ending with deleting `folder1`.

Instead, what happens is that the files are being deleted and after that, an exception is thrown and the folders remain.

> filesystem error: cannot remove all: Permission denied [.\path\to\folder1]

I'm compiling with **gcc 7.3.0** on Windows 7. Unfortunately, with this compiler I can't check and see if the same exception occurs with the `std::filesystem`.

I've also tried executing the program as administrator, but still the same exception is thrown.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43857050/6608142), I understand that there used to be a bug, which was fixed though.

So now my question is, if I understand the usage of `remove_all()` wrong, if I missed some settings I have to make in order to use this function properly or if there might be another bug in its implementation.

Comment: ***program as administrator, but still the same exception is thrown.*** Is this folder in Program Files or some other folder that requires a UAC elevation?

Comment: @drescherjm No, it lies in a simple folder on my normal drive. No system or other special folders. I can also delete it manually without elevation.

Comment: a) Visual Studio 2017 has filesystem header so if you are not limited by your disk space of internet connection you can try that. b) you could try simple system("del bla.txt"); and see if that works.